# VT x is not active in Virtualbox Guest OS

Tags: android, virtualbox

I have enabled **Virtualization in BIOS** of my system and it is working fine in the host system.
In my virtualBox setting I configured the
[Guest OS VT-x Configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwlHS.png)
But the problem is that the same is not working in Virtualbox Guest OS. The operating system is Windows 8.1. I changed the Paravirtualization Interface to all the items in list but no result. I get the following 
[Guest OS Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQrTP.png) 
Please help me to correct this error.

Thanks